# Scrollable tab view inside ion-tabs not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement ion-scroll inside ion-tabs. the idea is ion-tabs are at bottom of screen and on one particular tab I want a scrollable tab bar at top, for that I'm using ion-scroll.

Things that are working :

- ion-tabs work fine.
- ion-scroll works fine [ only scroll ]

Things that is the issue :

- elements inside ion-scroll are not clickable. i'm not getting their
  click event at all.

My tabs.html has following code :

```html
<!-- Add Contact Tab -->
<ion-tab title="Add Contact" badge="requestCount" style="badge-assertive" icon-off="ion-plus" icon-on="ion-plus" href="#/tab/addContacts/forwardOrConnect" class="gtab_label">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-add_contact"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<!-- Profile Tab -->
<ion-tab title="Profile" icon-off="ion-clipboard" icon-on="ion-clipboard" href="#/tab/myProfile/basicDetails">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-profile"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<ion-tab title="New Profile" icon-off="ion-clipboard" icon-on="ion-clipboard" href="#/tab/newProfile">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-newProfile"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

Now for the add contact tab, ion-nav content is as follows :

```html
<ion-content>
    <div class="tabslider">
        <ion-scroll direction="x" class="scrollh">
            <button class="button" ng-click="goToSlide($index)" ng-repeat="tab in tabs">{{tab.text}}</button>
        </ion-scroll>
    </div>
    <ion-slide-box style="height: 100%;" show-pager="false" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
        <ion-slide>
            <ion-scroll style="height:100%" delegate-handle="slide1Scroll" >
              <h3>content</h3>
            </ion-scroll>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
            <ion-scroll style="height:100%">
              <h3>content</h3>
            </ion-scroll>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
</ion-content>
```

Has anyone faced similar issue or any other better way to achieve this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried with `<ion-content scroll="true" direction="x" ...>`? it used to solve one problem i had with multiple scrolls (not the same case than you, but it might)